# How to clear the Cache inside the Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azureportal

**I have created a VM Image long back and it is deleted also.
But When I create any new VMs, it is always showing that image name in the Images list**:

[image]
[image]

**What I have tried to clear this**:

1. I have checked in Images Window where I do not have any previously created custom images:

[image]
[image]

2. Clearing the browser cache, history
3. Log-out of the Azure Portal and Sign-in again
4. Restarted the System.
5. Even in the Azure Portal Global Search History also cleared:

[image]

6. Logged in to Azure Portal Via different browsers.

But no luck on clearing this!

**How to clear the VM Images history in the VM Creation Page of Azure Portal?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the results successfully like below:***

I have created sample custom images and deleted but it always showing that image name in the Images list like below:

[image]

To resolve this issue, you can make use of ***Restore default settings***

**In your portal -> My information -> click Restore default settings** You'll be prompted to confirm this action.

[image]

To confirm in portal, now created a VM Image is not showing in the image list like below:

[image]

> ***Note***: ***By clicking this button will reset the default Dashboard and also remove all cached data. This option doesn't affect dashboard customizations.***

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nw8MNL9.png - Last Viewed should not be cleaned. So, can you give me any idea to remove only deleted VM Custom Images from the VM Creation Page.

Comment: AFAIK, this is only way we can clear our  deleted vm custom images